# Using the "\\" inside the \affil{} prints a comma instead of skipping to the next line.

Tags: titles

I want to add "Correspondence should be addressed to author1" to my title. So tried the following but instead of skipping to the next line "\\" prints a comma. Here is a minimum working example.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{abstract}


\begin{document}
    \title{\vspace{-1.0cm}Concise Title.}
    \author[1]{Author 1}
    \author[1]{Author 2}
    \affil[1]{\small Blah1, Blah2, U.S.A \\  Correspondence should be addressed to author1; author1@tex.com}

    \date{\vspace{-5ex}}

    \twocolumn[
    \begin{@twocolumnfalse}
        \maketitle
        \begin{abstract}
            \normalsize
            \blindtext

            \vspace{1cm} 
        \end{abstract}
    \end{@twocolumnfalse}
    ]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If I use \newline instead I get the desired result but the alignment is lost.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{abstract}


\begin{document}
    \title{\vspace{-1.0cm}Concise Title.}
    \author[1]{Author 1}
    \author[1]{Author 2}
    \affil[1]{\small Blah1, Blah2, U.S.A \newline  Correspondence should be addressed to author1; author1@tex.com}

    \date{\vspace{-5ex}}

    \twocolumn[
    \begin{@twocolumnfalse}
        \maketitle
        \begin{abstract}
            \normalsize
            \blindtext

            \vspace{1cm} 
        \end{abstract}
    \end{@twocolumnfalse}
    ]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package suggests to use `\authorcr` to break lines in the `\author` field, but it also works in `\affil`.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{abstract}

\begin{document}

\title{\vspace{-1.0cm}Concise Title.}
\author[1]{Author 1}
\author[1]{Author 2}
\affil[1]{\small Blah1, Blah2, U.S.A \authorcr
 Correspondence should be addressed to author1; author1@tex.com}

\date{\vspace{-5ex}}

\twocolumn[
\begin{@twocolumnfalse}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\normalsize
\blindtext

\vspace{1cm} 
\end{abstract}
\end{@twocolumnfalse}
]
\end{document}
```

[image]